# getting more then one column on an inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

i have the following query:

```
SELECT c.company_id, c.company_title, c.featured, a.address, a.postal_code, pc.city, pc.region,cat.category_title, p.phone
FROM dloc.companies c 
    INNER JOIN dloc.address a ON ( c.address_id = a.address_id  )  
  INNER JOIN dloc.postal_code pc ON ( a.postal_code = pc.postal_code )
  INNER JOIN dloc.company_categories cc ON ( c.company_id = cc.company_id )
  INNER JOIN dloc.categories cat ON ( cc.category_id = cat.category_id )
  INNER JOIN dloc.phones p ON ( c.company_id = p.company_id )

WHERE c.company_title like '%gge%'
```

everything works just fine.
the only thing is.. well. `phones` contains more then one phone number for some companies...
and i guess i get only the first one... or random, im not sure.
how can i rewrite this query so it will return all the phone numbers for each company?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion over whether the OP is asking for 'all phone numbers in one row', or 'multiple rows with one phone number each'.

Comment: any would be ok, but i think i have a problem with the db, only one phone per company.. i must have imported it wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll need to craft any application code to handle whichever choice.  Also, depending on use case, the various answers/comments that have suggested `left joins` should be considered.  And the most probable reason for single phone numbers is that your import did not contain duplicates (either because of actual data, or some constraint - duplicate or otherwise - on the data).  If you are expecting that all phone numbers from the same company will be in sequence, see the new edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that query, you should get one row for *each* phone number row (per company).  SQL works as relationship/set math/theory - having a '-many' relationship means multiple rows returned (So, your query should already be perfroming the desired behaviour).

Often, the problem people writing queries experience isn't getting multiple rows - it's restricting it to the desired 'single' row.

---

EDIT:

Result Ordering -
SQL, by convention, returns things *unordered*, **unless** some sort of explicit ordering is given (through the use of an `ORDER BY` clause).  You are seeing 'random' phone numbers being returned 'first' because the RDBMS still has to read/return results sequentially; this order is determined at runtime (...usually), when the system picks what indicies to use while accessing data.  The full interaction is rather complex (and is probably vendor specific), so just keep this in mind:
**UNLESS YOU SPECIFY ORDERING OF YOUR RESULTS, THE RESULTS ARE RETURNED IN A RANDOM ORDER**
*period*.

Comment: +1 but I think you meant each "phone number row" not each "unqiue phone number" There's no DISTINCT or GROUP BY that would force a unique result

Comment: @ConradFrix - I did mean phone number row (I was assuming each row held a unique number (per company)).  Edited to disambiguate, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on the `p.phone` field.

A few considerations, though:

- It looks like a company can have more than one phone. But also, none! So you should change your `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` to take that into consideration.
- It also looks like a company can have more than one address. If that's true, not only previous consideration should be taken into, but also you should rework your query to accommodate this.

Comment: a company can have none to 5 phones, a company can have only one address, but multiple companies can have the same address. thats why i seperated that table.

Comment: A company with no phone is not going to be listed when use use INNER JOIN. You should change it to `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You should get all phone numbers for the given company id because the join begins by doing a cartesian product between the two tables and then removing all "rows" that doesn't match the criteria in the join.

Comment: He want the phonenumbers all on the same row, not in different rows.

Answer (score 0):

`group_concat` will collect all phonenumbers in one column.
Add a `group by` on company_id, if you are sure no other values are listed more than once per company.
If not, put those 'duplicate' *(for want of a better word)* values in a `group_concat` as well.

```
SELECT 
  c.company_id
  , c.company_title
  , c.featured
  , a.address
  , a.postal_code
  , pc.city
  , pc.region
  , cat.category_title
  , GROUP_CONCAT(p.phone) as phonenumbers
FROM dloc.companies c 
INNER JOIN dloc.address a ON ( c.address_id = a.address_id  )  
INNER JOIN dloc.postal_code pc ON ( a.postal_code = pc.postal_code )
INNER JOIN dloc.company_categories cc ON ( c.company_id = cc.company_id )
INNER JOIN dloc.categories cat ON ( cc.category_id = cat.category_id )
INNER JOIN dloc.phones p ON ( c.company_id = p.company_id )
WHERE c.company_title like '%gge%'
GROUP BY c.companyid
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat